# struct as return type of function

Tags: c

While reading [C traps and Pitfalls](http://www.literateprogramming.com/ctraps.pdf), I came across following code snippet:

```
struct logrec{
    int date;
    int time;
    int code;  
}            // semicolon is missing

main()
{
..
..
}
```

Note that semicolon is missing after } and this makes `main()` returning structure.

Rather than asking question for `main()` returning struct [because `main()` returning other than int is undefined behavior] ,so I would like to ask question for any other `fun()`. for example

```
struct Abc{int a;} fun(){
    Abc a1;    //Error : Unknown type name 'Abc'
}

int main(){
.....
}
```

As it is mentioned in comment statement `Abc a` giving error *Unknown type Abc*.

So I have two questions regarding this:

1. What is scope of struct Abc?
2. If I can not declare any variable of type Abc inside `fun()` then How
   can I return struct Abc?

Comment: `logrec` is not in that PDF?

Comment: Ohh actually I have a hard copy that didn't notice the edition, sry for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a simple syntax error. `Abc` is not the same type as `struct Abc`.

Change:

```
struct Abc{int a;} fun(){
    Abc a1;    //Error : Unknown type name 'Abc'
}
```

to:

```
struct Abc{int a;} fun(){
    struct Abc a1;
} //^^^^^^
```

Comment: This could work too - `typedef struct Abc{int a;}Abc;`. Isn't it ?

Comment: OK now I can even declare it in main()..thanks ,sorry for silly question

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar: I don't know if you noticed, but it tells you in that PDF that it is a syntax error already. (See page 8 of 29)

Comment: @Noob: yes, a typedef which aliases both types is generally the better way to go.

Comment: @staticx, No it is not mentioned , section 2.3 Watch those semicolons!

Comment: @A.s.Bhullar: Look at the PDF again. It tells you right there what PaulR posted. It says, "Another place that a semicolon can make a big difference is at the end of a declaration just before a
function definition...There is a semicolon missing between the first
} and the f that immediately follows it. The effect of this is to declare that the function f returns a struct foo , which is defined as part of this declaration. If the semicolon were present, f would be defined by default as returning an integer."